Using highlightlines option for embedded minted code in a newtcblisting
I created a self-made newtcblisting which puts a beautiful frame around a minted code listing with an additional customizable header.
However, I am wondering if it is possible to make use of minted's hightlightlines option, so that certain lines in the embedded code are highlighted with a background color.
This is a minimal working example, demonstrating my custom codebox an a minted environment with the highlightlines option below.
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{dunkelgrau}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{hellgrau}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.08}
\definecolor{weiss}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0}
\definecolor{light-blue}{HTML}{eaf2fa}

\newcommand{\highlightblue}[1]{\colorbox{light-blue}{#1}}


\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[most,minted]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{expkv-def}

\usepackage{minted}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,minted}

\ekvdefinekeys{codebox}
{
   store title = \mycodeboxTitle
  ,store font = \mycodeboxFont
  ,store lang = \mycodeboxLang
  ,initial lang = cpp
}

\newtcblisting{codebox}[2][]{%
    breakable,
    colback=hellgrau,
    coltitle=weiss,
    colbacktitle=dunkelgrau,
    colframe=dunkelgrau,
    boxrule=0.9pt,
    boxsep=5pt,
    arc=1pt,
    fonttitle=\sffamily,
    toptitle=0mm,
    bottomtitle=0mm,
    left=3pt,
    right=3pt,
    listing only,
    code={\ekvset{codebox}{#1}},
    title={
      \ifstrequal{#2}{file}{\faFile*[regular]\hspace{5mm}}{%
        \ifstrequal{#2}{console}{\faTerminal\hspace{5mm}}{%
          \ifstrequal{#2}{info}{\faInfo\hspace{5mm}}{%
            \ifstrequal{#2}{book}{\faBookOpen\hspace{5mm}}{}%
          }
        }
      }\mycodeboxTitle
    },
    minted options app={
        fontsize=\mycodeboxFont,
        escapeinside=||
    },
    minted language=\mycodeboxLang,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{codebox}[title=include/adjustSpeed.hpp, font=\small, lang=cpp]{file}
#include <string>

std::string getHello() {
    return "Hello World";
}
\end{codebox}

\begin{minted}[highlightlines={4}, highlightcolor=light-blue, fontsize=\small]{cpp}
#include <string>

std::string getHello() {
    return "Hello World";
}
\end{minted}

\end{document}



I tweak the preamble to make it more concise. Some of packages will be loaded by the other packages. e.g., tcolorbox will load xcolor, minted option in tcolorbox will load package minted. most option in tcolorbox will loads all libraries except minted, documentation, and xparse.
The options highlightlines={4}, highlightcolor=light-blue can be added to the minted options app key in order to highlight the code in your customized box. You could add another argument to specify the line number which you want it to be highlighted. Here is the working example:
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[most,minted]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{dunkelgrau}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{hellgrau}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.08}
\definecolor{weiss}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0}
\definecolor{light-blue}{HTML}{eaf2fa}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{expkv-def}
\ekvdefinekeys{codebox}
{
   store title = \mycodeboxTitle,
   store font = \mycodeboxFont,
   store lang = \mycodeboxLang,
   initial lang = cpp
}
\newtcblisting{codebox}[3][]{%
    breakable,
    colback=hellgrau,
    coltitle=weiss,
    colbacktitle=dunkelgrau,
    colframe=dunkelgrau,
    boxrule=0.9pt,
    boxsep=5pt,
    arc=1pt,
    fonttitle=\sffamily,
    toptitle=0mm,
    bottomtitle=0mm,
    left=3pt,
    right=3pt,
    listing only,
    code={\ekvset{codebox}{#1}},
    title={
      \ifstrequal{#2}{file}{\faFile*[regular]\hspace{5mm}}{%
        \ifstrequal{#2}{console}{\faTerminal\hspace{5mm}}{%
          \ifstrequal{#2}{info}{\faInfo\hspace{5mm}}{%
            \ifstrequal{#2}{book}{\faBookOpen\hspace{5mm}}{}%
          }
        }
      }\mycodeboxTitle
    },
    minted options app={
        fontsize=\mycodeboxFont,
        escapeinside=||,
        highlightlines={#3}, highlightcolor=light-blue
    },
    minted language=\mycodeboxLang,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{codebox}[title=include/adjustSpeed.hpp, font=\small,lang=cpp]{file}{1,4}
#include <string>

std::string getHello() {
    return "Hello World";
}
\end{codebox}
\end{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Edit: To achieve the optional key like lines, you need to set the key minted options app to fully expanded, like minted options app/.expanded. But this raise another problem, that the key fontsize cannot be fully expanded. So you need to add \noexpand in front of \mycodeboxFont,like fontsize=\noexpand\mycodeboxFont. Here is the working example:

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[most,minted]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{dunkelgrau}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{hellgrau}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.08}
\definecolor{weiss}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0}
\definecolor{light-blue}{HTML}{eaf2fa}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{expkv-def}
\ekvdefinekeys{codebox}
{
   store title = \mycodeboxTitle,
   store font = \mycodeboxFont,
   store lang = \mycodeboxLang,
   initial lang = cpp,
   store lines = \mycodeboxLines
}
\newtcblisting{codebox}[3][]{%
    breakable,
    colback=hellgrau,
    coltitle=weiss,
    colbacktitle=dunkelgrau,
    colframe=dunkelgrau,
    boxrule=0.9pt,
    boxsep=5pt,
    arc=1pt,
    fonttitle=\sffamily,
    toptitle=0mm,
    bottomtitle=0mm,
    left=3pt,
    right=3pt,
    listing only,
    code={\ekvset{codebox}{#1}},
    title={
      \ifstrequal{#2}{file}{\faFile*[regular]\hspace{5mm}}{%
        \ifstrequal{#2}{console}{\faTerminal\hspace{5mm}}{%
          \ifstrequal{#2}{info}{\faInfo\hspace{5mm}}{%
            \ifstrequal{#2}{book}{\faBookOpen\hspace{5mm}}{}%
          }
        }
      }\mycodeboxTitle
    },
    minted options app/.expanded={
        fontsize=\noexpand\mycodeboxFont,
        escapeinside=||,
        highlightlines={\mycodeboxLines},highlightcolor=red!20
    },
    minted language=\mycodeboxLang,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{codebox}[title=include/adjustSpeed.hpp, font=\small,lang=cpp,lines={3,4}]{file}
#include <string>

std::string getHello() {
    return "Hello World";
}
\end{codebox}
\end{document}



This is absolutely fantastic, thank you so much.
One remark: since this is a breaking change with a new additional mandatory argument, I wondered if it can also be resolved with an additional optional key like "lines". I tried but was unsuccessful.

@taocp See the edits.

Thank you very much, Tom, this is really incredible.
